# How to show the existence of the sequence using the Kaplansky's density theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\xi,\eta\in\mathcal H$ where $\eta\perp\overline{A'\xi}$ where $A\subset\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ is a unital $*$-algebra. How do I show that there is a sequence $\{ a_n\}\subset A_{sa}\cap(A)_1$ such that $\|\xi-a_n\xi\|\leq n^{-1}$ and $\|a_n\eta\|\leq n^{-1}2^{-n}$ using the Kaplansky's density theorem?

Here $A_{sa}$ is the self-adjoint operators in $A$ and $(A)_1$ is the closed unit ball of $A$.

I can see that $[A'\xi]\in (A'')_1\cap (A'')_{sa}=\overline{(A)_1}^{SOT}\cap \overline{A_{sa}}^{SOT}$ using the theorem. But I don't see how I can extract the sequence from $A_{sa}\cap(A)_1$ satisfying the above conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key observation is that $A_{sa}$ is convex, so its sot closure agrees with its wot. So,  if $p$ is your projection, there exists a net $\{b_j\}$ such thaht $$b_j\to p\ \  \text{ sot};$$ then $b_j\to p$ wot, and so $b_j^*\to p$ wot. Then $$(b_j+b_j^*)/2\to p$$ gives  a net of selfadjoints  that converges wot to $p$. As $\overline{A_{sa}}_{\rm sot}=\overline{A_{sa}}^{\rm wot}$, there exists a net $\{a_j'\}$ in $A_{sa}$ with $a_j\to p$. Now applying the proof of Kaplansky to $a_j'$, we let 
$$
a_j=f(a_j'),
$$ 
where
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases} 
1,&\ t\geq1\\
t,&\ -1\leq t\leq 1\\
-1,&\ t\leq -1
\end{cases}
$$
Then we have a new net $\{a_j\}$ with $\|a_j\|\leq1$ and still $a_j\to p$, since
$$
f(a_j)\to f(p)=p.
$$

Finally, when you specialize $\xi$, you can extract a subsequence $\{a_n\}$ of $\{a_j\}$ such that $a_n\xi\to p\xi$.

Comment: I want this sequence to be in the unit ball at the same time. Your proof doesn't show that.

Comment: Yes, there was a sentence missing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the fact that how to do functional calculus to get the new net inside the unit ball?

Comment: Edited. $\ \ \ $

Comment: Thanks. I think we have to choose the $f$ so that it vanishes at infinity? Either way, I get the idea now.

Comment: No, you are applying the $f$ individually to a selfadjoint element. All you need is that $f$ is continuous on the spectrum, which is always bounded. What $f$ does outside of $\sigma(a_j')$ is irrelevant.

Comment: But we don't have uniform control over the sepctra of the net, do we? Isn't it going to be problem?

Comment: As I said, you are applying the $f$ **individually** to a selfadjoint element.

Comment: The nontrivial part is not that, but the fact that $f$ is sot-continuous. That works because a sufficient condition for it is that $\limsup_{|t|\to\infty}\frac{|f(t)|}{|t|}=0$.